# Calculation of third field based on two other field in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 2 fields on on Mongoose model: totalAttempts and totalRight. I am planning to calculate accuracy based on them.

```
totalAttempts: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
},
totalRight: { 
    type: Number,
    default: 1
}
```

This is what I have done [it doesn't work]

```
 accuracy:{
     type:Number,
     required:function() {return (this.totalRight/this.totalAttempts*100).toFixed(2)}
}
```

Also, if I don't put default value on Accuracy  I get an error:

```
ERROR; While creating new question ..ValidationError: Path `accuracy` is require                      d.

events.js:163
```

What will be the right way to accomplish this ? I already have a working solution to get totalAttempts and totalRight every time user request that Model. But I want to save that calculation and store info on my database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre save is the right way to go. Add it to your schema.

```
ModelSchema
.pre('save', function(next){
  this.accuracy = this.totalRight/this.totalAttempts*100).toFixed(2)
  next();   
});
```

Change `accuracy` definition to:

```
accuracy: {
     type: Number
}
```

Comment: I am still getting ERROR; While creating new question ..ValidationError: Path `accuracy` is required.

events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongooseError: Question validation failed

Comment: I suppose you meant `default` by `required` in your question. So, you if you remove required from accuracy it should work. `pre save` is called after the validations are run. That's why in your case `required` validation is failing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate it before you save the document.
You just need to add a virtual field that gets the value of accuracy when you need it

```
yourSchema.virtual("accuracy").get(function () {
    return this.totalRight/this.totalAttempts*100).toFixed(2)
});
```

now when you query this document you will get accuracy but don't forget to use `.toJSON({ virtuals: true })` on your document query

---

for more about virtuals in mongoose check [mongoose virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html).
when using lean use this plugin [mongoose-lean-virtuals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-lean-virtuals).

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 accuracy:{
     type: Number,
     required:true,
     default: function() {
     return (this.totalRight/this.totalAttempts*100).toFixed(2)
}}
```